# how to monitor if radclient packet disconnection has been successful received

Tags: shell, freeradius

I have the following question:

I would like to execute in a bash script the radclient command to force the user to be disconnected, but how I can monitor the result of packet disconnection if it has received and acknowledged?

I was thinking something:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "User-Name=value1,Acct-Session-Id=value2" | radclient -x IP_XXXXXX:1700 disconnect secret
```

if packet received and acknowledged then exit code (1) else exit code (0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `grep` to check for a line in the output like:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "User-Name=value1,Acct-Session-Id=value2" | radclient -x IP_XXXXXX:1700 disconnect secret | grep -Fq 'rad_recv: Disconnect-ACK packet'
```

Example:

```
bash script.sh
echo "$?"  ## Can produce 0 or 1 depending on the exit value of `grep`.
```

If you intend to do the test inside the script of course you can just use `if`:

```
if echo "User-Name=value1,Acct-Session-Id=value2" | radclient -x IP_XXXXXX:1700 disconnect secret | grep -Fq 'rad_recv: Disconnect-ACK packet'; then
    ...
else
    ...
fi
```

Or more readable:

```
echo "User-Name=value1,Acct-Session-Id=value2" | radclient -x IP_XXXXXX:1700 disconnect secret | grep -Fq 'rad_recv: Disconnect-ACK packet'
if [[ $? -eq 0 ]]; then
    ...
else
    ...
fi
```

Besides using `grep` you can also check for the pattern with `==` and `=~`:

```
RESULT=$(echo "User-Name=value1,Acct-Session-Id=value2" | radclient -x IP_XXXXXX:1700 disconnect secret)
[[ $RESULT == *'rad_recv: Disconnect-ACK packet'* ]]
...
```

Or

```
[[ $RESULT =~ 'rad_recv: Disconnect-ACK packet' ]]
```

Comment: This works for me if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    ...
else
    ...
fi

Comment: @user3155074 I see. You're shell must not be `bash`.

Comment: I changed that tag then.

Answer (score 0):

Just check the exit status. NAKs will cause radclient to return a none 0 exit status. Or at least that's the case in v3.0.x radclient.